# Use public function as sorting criteria, C++;

Tags: c++, sorting, set, functor

Consider this example, I have public function less that I want to use as a comparator.
P.S. I know if I change it to `operator<` it will work.

```
class A {
    std::string str;
    int id;
public:
    virtual bool less(A const& rhs) const{
        return id < rhs.id;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<A, A::less> s;
}
```

This gives me an error that less is not a valid template.
Can anyone please help me to pass lass as a comparator?
If its not possible can you tell me any workaround without touching the class itself.

Comment: why it's virtual at first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter of `std::set` needs to be a *type*, not a *value*.

It also has to be a type where `comp(a, a)` is a valid expression, where `comp` is a value of the compare type, and `a` is a value of the element type, so we can't use a pointer-to-member-function directly.

```
std::set<A, decltype(std::mem_fn(&A::less))> s(std::mem_fn(&A::less)));
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use the operator< than you can use a wrapper type which handles the compassion like this:

```
class A {
    std::string str;
    int id;
public:
    virtual bool less(A const& rhs) const{
        return id < rhs.id;
    }
};
struct A_wrapped{
    bool operator()(const A&a, const A&b) {
        return a.less(b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::set<A, A_wrapped> s;
}
```

This has the advantage that you do not have to pass anything to the constructor, the type definition is sufficient to tell it the usage of you own comparision.

Comment: its not "the only possible solution"

Comment: I guess it should be `std::set<A, A_wrapped> s;`

Comment: @Damien yes, thank you. Copy-and-past error.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What other possibility do exists?

Comment: *Compare* does not require *FunctionObject*, it can be a function pointer or member function pointer type.

Comment: a free function can be used: https://godbolt.org/z/rahj5c, or see Caleths answer that uses the member function

Comment: You are right, I forgot that you can pass a instance of the comparsion type into the ctor.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a less-than operator in the global scope that'll just call `less()`. This satisfies your criteria of not modifying the class:

```
class A {
    std::string str;
    int id;
public:
    virtual bool less(A const& rhs) const{
        return id < rhs.id;
    }
};

bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) {
    return lhs.less(rhs);
}

int main()
{
    std::set<A> s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can define a comparer.

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto comp = [](const A& a, const A& b){return a.less(b);};
    std::set<A,decltype(comp)> s{comp};
}
```